# og:image not displaying on my blog

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-opengraph

This is not a duplicate thread because last two days I have been trying every possible suggestion on this site, and still my `Like` image refuses to pop up on facebook.

My website is [here](http://www.karmafriendly.com)

No errors in debugger. In my multiple attempts to try various permutations combinations, facebook suddenly started to evaluate my site as spam. Instead on like button , my friends now see confirm button. For now I have removed Like button but still have share button on my website.

Image is rounded - 400 by 400; jpg and fits possible criteria.

I would be delighted to find out what is it I should have done to get my `og:image` on facebook.

Again, there are no errors on debugger as well.

Thanks
Rahul Trivedi

Comment: Browser cache? did you clean that?

Comment: I could make the image to work by pointing the link to image on my friends facebook profile. Since facebook server was pointing to facebook image - it showed up. Best part is that facebook somehow decided that my website is a spam so any facebook user is now warned that my website could be damaging. Amazing isn't it ! You create a website with so much effort but ONLY FACEBOOK could figure out that its a SPAM.